# How to prove that : $ \mathrm{Hom} ( A(G), H) \simeq \mathrm{Hom} (G , I(H)) $?

Tags: category-theory

How do we show that the functor $ A : \mathrm {Gr} \to \mathrm {Ab} $ defined by $ A (G) = G / [G, G] $ is a left adjoint functor of the inclusion functor : $ I : \mathrm {Ab} \to \mathrm {Gr} $ ?.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the universal property of the commutator subgroup?

Comment: Not very familiar. All thing i know about that is : $ G/[G,G] $ represents the functor : $ F(A) = \{ \ f \in \mathrm{Hom} ( G , A ) \ , A \in \mathrm{Ab} \ \} $. Is it true ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I don't really get how you are trying to define $F$ here. This seems like it is supposed to be a fairly straightforward exercise in adjoint functors, but it assumes basic familiarity with the properties of the commutator subgroup.

Comment: Can you help me to resolve it ? I can't do it alone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Show that if $\varphi: G\to A$ is a homomorphism with $A$ abelian, then $[G,G]$ is contained in the kernel of $\varphi$.

Comment: So : $ G/[G,G] $ represents the functor $ F(A) = \{ \ f \in \mathrm{Hom} ( G , A ) \ , \ [G,G] \subset \mathrm{ker} \ f \ , \ A \in \mathrm{Ab} \ \} $, no ?.

Comment: I do not see how that defines anything. It seems to use A for two different things.

Comment: @Bryan261 Based on your previous questions, it seems as if your background in mathematics has some gaps. I strongly urge you to say what you understand and what you don't – and "I don't understand anything" is not acceptable.

Comment: If, $ \varphi : G \to A $ is a group homomorphism, then : $ f([G,G] ) \subset [A,A] $. if $ A \in \mathrm{Ab} $, then : $ [A,A] = \{ e \} $, consequently, $ [G,G] \subset \mathrm{ker} \ \varphi $, no ?

Comment: @Zhen Lin : I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes, if $G \to A$ is a group homomorphism and $A$ is abelian, then $[G, G]$ is in the kernel. Next, can you show that $G / [G, G]$ is abelian?

Comment: $ \forall ( \overline{a} , \overline{b} ) \in G/[G,G] \times G/[G,G] $ : $ \overline{a} \overline{b} \overline{a}^{-1} \overline{b}^{-1} = \overline{aba^{-1}b^{-1}} = \overline{e} $. Therfore, $ \overline{a} \overline{b} = \overline{b} \overline{a} $. So : $ G/[G,G] $ is abelien. no ?

Answer (score 1):

The quotient $G/[G,G]$ is known as the *abelianization* $G^{\rm ab}$. First check that $[G,G]$, the subgroup generated by the commutators, is indeed a normal subgroup: indeed, conjugation distributes over commutators as $[x,y]^a=[x^a,y^a]$. Next, check that $G\mapsto G^{\rm ab}$ is indeed functorial. Given a map between groups $\varphi:G\to H$, what is the corresponding $\varphi^{\rm ab}:G^{\rm ab}\to H^{\rm ab}$? You'll want to make sure it's well-defined! Check the obvious properties; $({\rm id}_G)^{\rm ab}={\rm id}_{G^{\rm ab}}$ and $(\varphi\circ\psi)^{\rm ab}=\varphi^{\rm ab}\circ\psi^{\rm ab}$.

Finally we want to exhibit a canonical isomorphism $\hom_{\rm Grp}(G,H)\cong\hom_{\rm Ab}(G^{\rm ab},H)$ for all groups $G$ and abelian groups $H$. Where do you think $\varphi:G\to H$ should be sent?

Comment: Thank you. To define $ \varphi^{\mathrm{ab}} $, we consider : $ \pi \circ \varphi : G \to H \to H^{\mathrm{ab}} $ as a morphism of groups, then, we apply the universal property of the commutator subgroups, we obtain a factorisation : $ \varphi^{\mathrm{ab}} : G^{\mathrm{ab}} \to H^{\mathrm{ab}} $. no ? Now, about the last question : if $ \Phi $ is the isomorphism between : $ \mathrm{Hom} ( G , H ) $ and $ \mathrm{Hom} ( G^{\mathrm{ab}} , H ) $, then, $ \varphi : G \to H $ should be sent to $ \Phi ( \varphi ) = \varphi^{\mathrm{ab}} : G^{\mathrm{ab}} \to H^{\mathrm{ab}} $, no ? Thanks a lot.